# How can I query the ASPNetUserLogins table in the new Microsoft Identity System?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

On a new site I allow people to sign up with either a local account (i.e. they fill out a form on my site listing their information or they can sign in with Facebook/Twitter, etc.  When they sign in with Facebook or Twitter, a record is added to the ASPNetUserLogins table - for reference the columns in the Table are

```
UserID
LoginProvider
ProviderKey
```

The UserID corresponds to the ID in the ASPNetUsers table, the login providers simply says either "Twitter" or Facebook" and the ProviderKey is the Facebook or Twitter ID number.  When one is using the Facebook MVC template the userid is the Facebook ID, which is the Provider key.

My question - *how can you query the ASPNetUserLogins table with the provider key?*

I want to be able to get the UserID from the ASPNetUserLogin table, and I have the ProviderKey so there are unique keys to be had - but there seems to be no way of accessing the ASPNetUsers table within the new Identity System.

Answer (score 1):

You want to call:

```
    public virtual Task<TUser> FindAsync(UserLoginInfo login)
```

And construct UserLoginInfo with the providerKey and loginProvider.

Comment: Strangely enough I try that method and I get the error of "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader' to type 'Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbDataReader'." even after I uninstall glimpse and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: UserLoginInfo is sealed which might cause issues with dynamic proxies

Comment: Hurm - it would at that - any idea how to get around that limitation?

Comment: Extend UserManager and provide another similar method that takes the two strings and feeds it into the user store directly?

Comment: I guess - it just seems that there should be some simple elegant way of getting the information - there doesn't seem to be though.